# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child in React App

Tags: node.js, material-ui

I am trying to build a react app using the following component:

Scream.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

//Mui Stuff
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';


const styles ={
    card:{
        display: 'flex'
    }
}

class Scream extends Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, scream : { body, createdAt, userImage, userHandle, screamId, likeCount, commentCount }} = this.props
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardMedia 
                image={userImage}
                title="Profile Image"/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{userHandle}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card> 
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Scream);
```

However I am getting the following error:

```html
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_seconds, _nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (created by ForwardRef(Typography))
    in ForwardRef(Typography) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Typography)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Typography)) (at Scream.js:27)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(CardContent))
    in ForwardRef(CardContent) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardContent)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardContent)) (at Scream.js:25)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(Card))
    in ForwardRef(Card) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)) (at Scream.js:21)
    in Scream (created by WithStyles(Scream))
    in WithStyles(Scream) (at home.js:25)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at home.js:29)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at home.js:28)
    in home (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:42)
    in Switch (at App.js:41)
    in div (at App.js:39)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:37)
    in ThemeProvider (at App.js:36)
    in div (at App.js:35)
    in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

my current version of material ui / core is 4.3.0, please is this a bug in the library because I have spent hours trying to debug my code. can anyone direct me to some material so that I can get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is,

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_seconds, _nanoseconds})

This means you are trying to render an object.

I think your error is due to this line,

```
<Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt}</Typography>
```

You must try this,

```
<Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt._seconds} {createdAt._nanoseconds}</Typography>
```